# problem using substring to see if a string contain the substring in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, youtube-dl

I am a beginner in batch and I have found a problem that I can't resolve.
the batch file is just a little script to make using "youtube-dl" (a command-lines tool for downloading youtube videos) more practical (the folder "youtube-dl.exe" is in is in PATH)

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /p url=url : 
set /p qual="quality (360/720 = 1/0) : "
if %qual%==0 (
    set qual=22
) else (
    set qual=18
)
cd C:\Users\theo\Videos
if not %url:&list=%==%url% (
    set /p v="video or playlist ? (V/P)"
    if %v%==P (
        youtube-dl.exe -f %qual% --yes-playlist "%url%"
    ) else (
        youtube-dl.exe -f %qual% --no-playlist "%url%"
    )
) else (
    youtube-dl.exe -f %qual% --no-playlist "%url%"
)
endlocal
cmd /k
```

the cmd window close instantly when the second `if` statement is reached and I just can't figure what is wrong !

EDIT: the solution of Jeb worked ^^

Comment: **Always** enclose your variables in IF statements. `IF not "%url:&list=%" == "%URL%" ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always enclose your variables in IF statements.
That's necessary for two reasons.

1. It avoids syntax errors, when the variable is empty, contains spaces, other delimiters or special characters like `&|<>...`.
2. It avoids problems with variable modifier syntax, like search/replace `!var:search=replace!` or substring syntax `!var:~<start>,<size>!`

**Delayed expansion**
Your second problem is that percent expansion occurs when a block is **parsed** before it is even executed.

Therefor `if %v%==P ...` never expands to the value of the entered `v`, instead it was expanded probably to nothing.

In blocks (or better, always) use delayed expansion.

```
if not "!url:&list=!" == "!url!" (
    set /p v="video or playlist ? (V/P)"
    if "!v!" == "P" (
        youtube-dl.exe -f !qual! --yes-playlist "!url!"
    ) else (
...
```